# Concatenate list with Yield

Tags: python, list, concatenation, yield

Where is the flaw in my reasoning? From my understanding yield works similar to a return statement that comes back to the generator to continue iterating. I was expecting the code to continue adding onto the list but I get an error.

```
def method(self):
    samplelist = []
    while(condition):
         #the data is collected
         samplelist = data
         yield samplelist

finalList += file.method()
```

EDIT:
My initial error was due to attempting to concatenate finalList using += when it didn't have an initialized value. This was resolved by using finalList.append(), however, yield still isn't working and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand why.

There was a fairly helpful answer posted and then deleted for some reason. But it explained that yield was really returning a generator object. From this I tried a few different things.

1 They also suggested to use list(file.method()) to iterate over it. However this further changed the type of finalList to a tuple and wasn't compatible with the rest of my code.

2 I tried to iterate over the object doing

```
for x in file_writer.write_records():
    sample.append(x)
```

But with the same result. How can I append the values from the generator object?

Comment: Your problem is that method is defined after it's being called, perhaps?

Comment: Note that the return value of `method` isn't a list, it's a generator object. You have to iterate over it with a `for` loop, or call `next` on the generator, or convert it into a list, if you want to access the yielded items.

Comment: @Kevin OP does not want to access the items, he wants to add them to a list. The `__iadd__` and `extend` method of `list` can handle iterators.

Comment: @sshashank124 " UnboundLocalError: local variable 'finalList' referenced before assignment " , which doesn't really make sense to me because if  I concatenate samplelist to another variable locally in method() and just return that variable to assign to finalList it works fine.

Comment: @Korem sorry it's written properly in my actual code, this is just pseudo really, edited it now

Comment: @JohnSmith There's no variable `sample` in the code you've shown so far, so nobody can really answer your question.

Comment: @sloth ugh rough morning, edited, should be finalList

Comment: @JohnSmith Do you declare `finalList` before running the line `finalList += file.method()`?

Comment: @sloth yes, it's global

Comment: The `UnboundLocalError` indicates `finalList` is not a global.

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example).

Comment: @martineau I have edited my post with updates and further trials, I hope this makes my problem more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to overlook the obvious, that being that `file.method()` isn't declared in your posted code, and therefore can not be called as you show. So I will refer to your generator function as `method()`. It would be useful if you could post code that worked, or that is at least consistent.

`method()` returns a generator, not a list. You can see this by

```
>>> method()
<generator object f at 0x7f8b7a5bda50
```

You need to resolve the generator. This can be done by calling `list()` on it:

```
finalList += list(method())
```

Now `finalList` will have the results of `method()` appended to it. Note that this will have invoked the generator many times until `condition` is met. Your code might seem to hang while new data is produced, however that is done. You can check this by adding a print statement after the yield to see control returned to the generator.

This will be more useful to you:

```
for l in method():
    finalList.extend(l)
    # process finalList....
```

Now control is returned to the calling code after each datum is produced, and the calling code has an opportunity to work on it.

BTW, you don't need to initialise `samplelist = []` as you rebind it in the loop.

Comment: I don't mean to append to samplelist, the rebind is fine for that I meant to append each rebind to finalList using yield except I'm not sure why it doesn't work

Comment: @JohnSmith updated answer following your clarification, such as it is.